# Iterate table and set values in a List type object

Tags: c#, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a `List<BankAccount> Company_Accounts` property in class `Company`. 
On `CreateCompany` page One or more `BankAccount` informations are being entered in table dynamically . I want javascript/jquery code to iterate each row and create a new `Account` type object and this push object in `Company_Accounts`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create your empty array, or get a previous array
$(#tableid tr).each(function(index, element) {
  // we are itering through every row of the table. Index is the number of the line (from 0), and element the line
  // here some treatment to read the columns and create a new AccountType
  // Check if same object already exist in table (maybe), if not push it back to the array
});
```

Cannot help you more without knowing the objects prototype, and if you wanna refresh the array everytime the table is modified or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Company{ 
               string Name{get; set;} 
               string address{get;set;} 
               IList<BankAccount> Accounts{get; set;}
             } 

class BankAccount{
                   Company CompanyName{get; set;} 
                   string BankName{get; set;} 
                   string AccountNo{get; set;} 
                   string BankAddress{get; set;}
                 } 
On create page for company i create and delete dynamically new BankAccount information by taking entry in Table's <td> cell having inputbox.
I have to bind the List of newly created BankAccount to the CompanyModel on view page
```